# Android GCM Not Registered Only At Lollipop

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-5.0-lollipop

I currently trying to use GCM on my App. I've tried to send push notifications to several Android phones that already installed my App, and most of them works fine, except the Lollipop ones which gave me the error below:

```
{"multicast_id":6609164900208197699,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}
```

**EDIT:**

I'm sorry everyone, just as many has suggested, it's not because of lollipop. I think it's because of new GCM methods which makes the registration id sometimes changes. And I haven't yet implemented `onTokenRefresh()`.

Comment: Have you implemented unregistering from GCM???

Answer (score 0):

Trace device token in Log cat and Cross check the Device token from your saved location and from the Log cat. I think you might be using incorrect Device token to send push notification.

Answer (score 0):

Its nothing like Lolipop or other devices. the response that you got clearly states that the device is not registered on GCM server.

Check with your GCM device registration code by adding breakpoint, you'll be probably saving the device id in shared prefrences. So clear the Data and cache of your app and run the application. your GCM should get registered.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to refer to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes) for the meaning of `NotRegistered` error and the possible course of actions that you can do. I think it doesn't have to do with the Android version that you are using.

> Unregistered Device
>
> 200 + error:NotRegistered
>
> An existing registration token may cease to be valid in a number of scenarios, including:
>
> - If the client app unregisters with GCM.
> - If the client app is automatically unregistered, which can happen if the user uninstalls the application. For example, on iOS, if the APNS Feedback Service reported the APNS token as invalid.
> - If the registration token expires (for example, Google might decide to refresh registration tokens, or the APNS token has expired for iOS devices).
> - If the client app is updated but the new version is not configured to receive messages.
>
> For all these cases, remove this registration token from the app server and stop using it to send messages.